# Do I need to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64) for my powerpoint Add-in?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, add-in

I am currently installing a Powerpoint Add-in which I have built in C#. in the prerequisites `Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64)` is listed. I have created a setup using the `ClickOnce` deployment. But I would idealy want my setup to not need admin rights.

The program `Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64)` needs admin rights to install... But do I need this program for my Add-In to work? It was in the prerequisites by defauly

Comment: You might find up-to-date answer here too - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5887c10d-b831-4050-b148-cc39fcfcb4bc/should-i-include-visual-studio-2010-tools-for-office-runtime?forum=vsto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From This link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/05/13/when-do-i-need-to-deploy-the-vsto-runtime.aspx)

> The Office extensions for .NET Framework 3.5 and Office extensions for .NET Framework 4. He also explained that starting in Microsoft Office 2010, the Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office runtime is included and does not need to be deployed alongside your Office solution – BUT – (currently) only if you are targeting the .NET Framework 3.5.
>
> If you are targeting the .NET Framework 4, the Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Runtime must be selected in the Prerequisites Dialog Box and installed on end-user computers. This is because the Office extensions for .NET Framework 4 are not included in the Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office runtime that is included in Microsoft Office 2010 Beta or RTM.

**Aside**

From my own personal experience. over the past year I have found that anything lower than Microsoft Office 2010 (2007 and below) needed to install [Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48217).